# Use local ssh_config settings on a remote server

Tags: ssh, rsync

Good day, friends!

I've got a locally configured `~/ssh/config` file with all the hosts set up as they should. I am using them successfully when doing my ssh from the local computer like `ssh dev`. But when I am on a remote server I cannot do it and get this error `Could not resolve hostname XYZ: Name or service not known`. I have configured my local keys to be passed to remote system with `ForwardAgent yes`, so I can use them when ssh-ing further from the remote machine. The only piece of a puzzle is being able to use my locally defined ssh config (and just maybe `known_hosts` too).

Please give any suggestions on how to achieve this.

For the context - I am setting up a remote dev environment in the cloud, from which I can rsync to and from productin servers.

Comment: There is nothing built in to OpenSSH to do this. There is 3rd party tools to sync your home dir, or deploy config files to multiple systems. You probably need to look at one of those. Tracking your homedir in git might be an option, or using something like ansible to deploy an ssh config to all the systems you need the config on.

Comment: Thanks, @Zoredache! Could you please recommend some of those 3rd party tools?

Comment: Lots of hits on google for [track homedir dotfile git](https://www.google.com/search?q=track+homedir+dotfiles+git), as for deploying, as I mentioned I use ansible, though salt, or some other configuration management tool would work, if you aren't using some configuration management engine, you might want to consider it.